# W3CHttpResponseCodec error while Selenium Driver runs over VPN in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

when I run my code without VPN my code works but when I connect VPN connection I get many errors such as:

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:277)
    at RequestWithSelenium.checkBody(RequestWithSelenium.java:71)
    at Main$3.run(Main.java:70)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My code explanation is simply that it tries to fetch sites which has includes error messages in body tag.

```
public void checkBody() {
        for(String siteFinder: webSites) {
            System.out.println("Selenium has visited " + siteFinder + " succesfully.");
            driver.get(siteFinder); 
            bodyCheck = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
            for(String errFinder: errorMsgs) {
                if(bodyCheck.contains(errFinder)) {
                    errorSites.add(siteFinder);
                }
            }
        }
        driver.close();
        if(errorSites.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("There is no down site has found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Down site(s) list has shown below.");
            int listMeter = 1;
            for(String downSites: errorSites) {
                System.out.println(listMeter + "th site: " + downSites);
                listMeter++;
            }
        }
        
}
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Are you running your code on remote driver?

Comment: @ZakariaShahed What do you mean by driver? I've been using this code on my personal computer with VPN, only that.